# Tangent application on product manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I have the following definition:

> Let M, N smooth manifolds, $f:M \rightarrow N $ a smooth function.
> Then the 'tangent application' $$T_p f : T_p M \rightarrow T_{f(p)} N
>  $$ is given for
>
> $$T_p f (v_p) g := v_p (g \circ f) $$ where $v_p: C^{\infty}(M)
>  \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a derivation

With that definition of 'tangent application', i must prove this:

> A Lie group is a smooth manifold G with a group structure such that
> $\mu : G \times G \rightarrow G$ (product function) is a smooth map.
> Knowing that $G\times G$ is also a Lie group,
>
> Show that the 'tangent application' $$T_{(a,b)} \mu: T_a G \times T_b
>  G \rightarrow T_{ab} G $$ is given for $$T_{(a,b)}\mu \cdot (v_a,w_b) 
>  = T_a R_b \cdot v_a + T_b L_a \cdot w_b$$ where $L_a$ and $R_b$ are the left and right product maps.

i tried to use that $T_{(a,b)} \mu \cdot (v_a,w_b) = T_{(a,b)}\mu \cdot (v_a,0) + T_{(a,b)} \mu \cdot (0,w_b)$ and the inclusion map concept $\alpha_a : G \rightarrow G \times G $, st. $\alpha_a (g) = (a,g) $ and $\beta_a: G \rightarrow G \times G $ st. $\beta_a(g)=(g,a)$ but i can't arrive at the result.

Thanks for read!

**EDIT:**

This is a possible resolution?

> $T_a G \times T_b G $ is a vector space, then
> $(v_a,w_b)=(v_a,0)+(0,w_b)$, and using that $T_{(a,b)} \mu $ is a
> linear application implies
>
> $T_{(a,b)} \mu (v_a,w_b) = T_{(a,b)} \mu (v_a,0) + T_{(a,b)} \mu
>  (0,w_b) $
>
> Now let $c:(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \rightarrow G $ such that $c(0)=a$ and
> $c'(0)=v_a$
>
> and $\gamma : (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \rightarrow G \times G$,
> $\gamma(t)=(c(t),b)$
>
> Then $T_{(a,b)} \mu (v_a,0) = \frac{d}{dt}(\mu \circ \gamma)  |_{t=0}
> > =\frac{d}{dt} \mu(c(t),b)|_{t=0}$
>
> On the other hand, if $R_b : G \rightarrow G$, $ a \mapsto \mu(a,b)$
>
> i consider $T_a R_b: T_a G \rightarrow T_{\mu(a,b)} G$
>
> Then $T_a R_b (v_a) = \frac{d}{dt} (R_b \circ c)|_{t=0} =
>  \frac{d}{dt}\mu(c(t),b)|_{t=0}$
>
> That implies $T_{(a,b)} \mu (v_a,0) = T_a R_b (v_a)$
>
> and analogously $T_{(a,b)} \mu (0,w_b) = T_b L_a (w_b)$

Comment: Shouldn't you assume that $v_p$ is a derivation?

Comment: yes, you are right. Thanks